# more elegant way to read 6 bytes from memory

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am executing the following code to read out a particular value 6 Bytes from an array.For me somehow the following looks ugly.I am running this code on a Little Endian Processor.
Is there some way I can make it more elegant.

```
temp_ts = (ptr[ts_offset]);
new_ts = temp_ts << 40;

temp_ts = (ptr[ts_offset + 1]);
new_ts |= temp_ts << 32;

temp_ts = (ptr[ts_offset + 2]);
new_ts |= temp_ts << 24;

temp_ts = (ptr[ts_offset + 3]);
new_ts |= temp_ts << 16;

temp_ts = (ptr[ts_offset + 4]);
new_ts |= temp_ts << 8;

temp_ts = (ptr[ts_offset + 5]);
new_ts |= temp_ts << 0;
```

Note: The code is working fine.This is question of style only.

Comment: I added a nice simplification in my post, which you could also apply to @Gene's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can code it as a loop and let the compiler do the unrolling:

```
for (new_ts = i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
  new_ts = (new_ts << 8) | ptr[ts_offset + i];
```

For what it's worth, I compiled this with `gcc 4.3.6` and `-O4`.  It does unroll nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
int offset = 0;
int shift = 40;
while (offset <= 5) { 
  temp_ts = ptr[ts_offset + offset];
  new_ts |= temp_ts << shift;
  offset++;
  shift -= 8;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like your redundant `<< 0`; again for symmetry, I also added the `+ 0` in:

```
p = ptr;
o = ts_offset;
new_ts = (p[o + 0] << 40) | (p[o + 1] << 32) | (p[o + 2] << 24) |
         (p[o + 3] << 16) | (p[o + 4] <<  8) | (p[o + 5] <<  0);
```

Or adding a simplification (others did not see):

```
unsigned char* p = ptr + ts_offset;
new_ts = (p[0] << 40) | (p[1] << 32) | (p[2] << 24) |
         (p[3] << 16) | (p[4] <<  8) | (p[5] <<  0);
```